# How to make Nginx Ingress allow SSL Pasthrough for "Bad certificates"

Tags: ssl, nginx-ingress, mtls

The goal is to manage mTLS on self-written service (ServiceA). It's exposed to public with Nginx Ingress controller.

Nginx Ingress was provided with `--enable-ssl-passthrough` flag, startup logs include `"Starting TLS proxy for SSL Passthrough"` message.

Ingress object of ServiceA includes the following annotations:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
```

Request through nginx fails on nginx side with error:
`SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A000412:SSL routines::sslv3 alert bad certificate:SSL alert number 42) while SSL handshaking to upstream`

To validate the setup without nginx, I'm sending `curl` requests with the same set of client certificates and passphrase attached to ServiceA service (port-forwarded) and it returns expected output only with `-k` (insecure) flag provided.

Also, since it's OSI level 4, it's worth noticing that there are other ingress objects serving the same domain name, but without `ssl-passthrough`. However, removing `backend-protocol: "HTTPS"` from the ingress object of ServiceA, the error states: `upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`. Therefor, I assume routing works as expected

How to allow Nginx ingress controller to allow insecure client certificates to be passed to the backend?